# React.js, view source is empty, is it bad for SEO?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a website using React.js (using React Router, not u Next.js). [liveitcourses.com](https://www.liveitcourses.com) is the name of the website which is still in progress.

But I am facing a strange issue. On every page of the website whenever I am trying to see the "view source", the tag body  is showing empty. I am afraid if it is not showing the body contents in the view source, search engines will not be able to crawl my pages, hence bad impact on SEO.

I just started React a few weeks ago. Is it the normal React behaviour or should I need to correct it? If my understanding is correct then how can I make my website crawlable for search engines. Please suggest.

Here is the HTML, body tag is empty while title and other meta tags are present:

```
<html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/><meta name="description" content="Learn IT courses online in interactive and live classes."/><link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous"/><title>Best online IT courses based on live classes and interactive programming sessions</title><script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.80f62ed5.js"></script><link href="/static/css/main.53eb7892.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div></body></html>
```

Comment: i am facing same issue, Can you please guide me.  you have found any solution with react js to view source code in side body content. or you have use any other way regarding SEO.

Comment: Hi Shammi I had to convert my website to NextJS, have a look https://www.liveitcourses.com/courses. Now I am able to see the content on view page source option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how React is, a library for making SPA (Single Page Application), where everything is handled via JavaScript in the browser. For an application made entirely with React, indeed, the server send this empty HTML template with scripts to be executed. You can use the inspection tool to see your content after they are executed.

And yeah it's bad for SEO as Search Engine Crowlers are on hurry (there is a limited time for a page). If that's something that matter for your application, you should try [Next.js](https://nextjs.org), [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com)... or use Server Side Rendering as known for decades with PHP, Node.js...

Comment: tnx for reply.  My pages are static pages. So far no dynamic content. In this case, when the actual body contents will be loaded? Not at all? I cannot see anything in the body tag even if I wait for few mins. So actually when whole page loads?

Comment: You are not seeing it in source code but the website is there visually, right ?

Comment: Use the inspection tool instead of the code source and you will see your content after the JS gets executed.

Comment: You are right i can see the content in the website on the browser as well as through the dev tool. But why the view source does not show it while inspection tool shows it? And does search engines use view source or inspection tool to crawl the page?

Comment: View source shows the HTML you get from the server, while the inspection shows the code after the scripts are executed.  Nowadays, search are making the effort to wait for the scripts to be executed (in a limited waiting time) but yeah, we can say that what’s really important should be in the "View source" for SEO.

Comment: You can use [NextJS static export](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export) to get static html result from ReactJS

Answer (score 1):

Reactjs is rendering code javascript with render in client, so if you view source code, you cant view it. if you click F12 and choose elements tab, you can view code is rended but it from load js file. So if you want to SEO for performance, you should choose SSR ( server side rendering), in reactjs is next.js, in vuejs is nuxt.js.